# SQL - Where Field has Changed Over Time

Tags: sql, time, duplicates, where-clause

I'm running SQL server management studio and my table/dataset contains approximately 700K rows. The table is a list of accounts each month. So at the begining of each month, a snapshot is taken of all the accounts (and who owns them), etc. etc. etc. and that is used to update the data-set. The 2 fields in question are AccountID and Rep (and I guess you could say month). This query really should be pretty easy but TBH, I have to move-on to other things so I thought I'd throw it up here to get some help.

Essentially, I need to extract distinct AccountIDs that at some point changed reps. See a screenshot below of what I'm thinking:

[image]

Thoughts?

--- I should note for instance that AccountID ABC1159 is not included in the results b/c it appears only once and is never handled by any other rep.

--- Also, another parameter is if the first time an account appears and the rep name appears in a certain list and then moves to another rep, that's fine. For instance, if the first instance of a Rep was say "Friendly Account Manager" or "Support Specialist" and then moves to another name, those can be excluded from the result field. So we essentially need a where statement or something that eliminates those results if the first instance appears in this list, then there is an instance where the name changed but non after that. The goal is to see if after the rep received a human rep (so they didn't have a name in that list), did they then change human reps at a certain point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to first isolate the distinct `AccountID` and `Rep` combinations, then you want to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to find `AccountID` values that have multiple `Rep` values:

```
SELECT AccountID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID, Rep
      FROM YourTable
      WHERE Rep NOT IN ('Support Specialist','Friendly Account Manager')
     )sub
GROUP BY AccountID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks Goat. That would satisfy the first parameter but i've gone back in and added a few more. Thoughts?

Comment: @Joshua you could us `NOT IN` to exclude certain values for `Rep`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.AccountID
FROM [table] t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [reps table] r WHERE r.Rep = t.Rep AND r.[is not human])
GROUP BY t.AccountID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.Rep) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a SELECT DISTINCT on the table and join the table to itself - something like this - with Account being the name I gave your table:

SELECT DISTINCT A1.AccountID, A1.Rep, A1.ReportMonth
FROM AccountTable.AccountID A1
    INNER JOIN AccountTable A2
    ON A1.AccountID = A2.AccountID
        AND A1.Rep <> A2.Rep
ORDER BY A1.AccountD